# Chrome Inspect CSS file version remove while override from local resource

Tags: google-chrome, inspect

Does anyone know how I can remove CSS version number while overriding a CSS file with the help of the Chrome Inspect tool?

Comment: We need more details on what you're trying to accomplish programatically. Stack Overflow is specifically for code-related issues that you may come across.

Comment: @SunnyPatel sorry for the confusion, see this screenshot https://ibb.co/47pmg67, I am overriding my CSS file with local, but I curious to know is it possible to remove the CSS version number with help of Inspect tool... Thanks!